# Theming  language in shopify

Tags: php, smarty

how can i create my own themeing tags/language or whatever its called like shopify is using? smarty has it also, sorry i dont know what its called.

for example in shopify if you type

```
    <h1> {{ product.title }} </h1> 
- this will print out the products title. what im wondering is how can i create my own language of this type using php?
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve. If you use php, why do you want to implement your own templating language and don't just use Smarty (or one of the gazillion alternatives)?

Answer (score 2):

Shopify's templating engine is called [Liquid](http://github.com/Shopify/liquid), and [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) is itself a templating engine. Use one of these in your app - don't bother implementing your own.

The basic way that they work is you pass them a template file, and a map of variables (such as the "product" variable in your example), and these are exposed as objects you can reference in the template.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a template language. PHP pretty much is a template language, since you can embed PHP code and drop variables into HTML.

People usually have `*.tpl` files in PHP which they designate as templates, and they're usually kept free of logic-heavy code, so that it looks more like the code you referenced above.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i create my own themeing
>   tags/language or whatever its called
>   like shopify is using?

Have a look at:

- [How to make a simple HTML template engine in PHP](http://www.broculos.net/tutorials/how_to_make_a_simple_html_template_engine_in_php/20080315/en)
- [Writing a Template System in PHP](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Display-Tutorials/Writing-a-Template-System-in-PHP/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here: being able to call product.title is most likely not a feature of the tempalte engine but of your object model (if any). I guess product.title calls the method / field on the object, which returns the title.